# Letting someone else pay in a check (made out to me) to their account?

Tags: canada, check, endorsement

I have a check made out to me (call me John Doe). I'm permanently away from my home country, where I have bank accounts; I'm now in Canada. I'd like to let a friend (call her Jane Doe) pay the check in to her account. Is this possible, and how can I do it?

http://www.bankingquestions.com/checkingaccounts/q_endorsetoanother.html suggests I can do this by 'endorsing' the check: writing "Pay to the order of Jane Doe" on the back and then signing me name below. But I wanted to check that this still worked, and would work in Canada.

Comment: Yes that will still work but ultimately is at the discretion of the bank. To improve your chances, add the line DEPOSIT ONLY (after your signature), this way as long as its not being cashed, there is less chance it will be rejected.

Comment: I'm mildly confused by the wording of the question. If I understand correctly, you are in possession of a check, but have no bank account locally in Canada. Furthermore, you would like to pass the check along to a friend, also in Canada, to deposit in her bank account. Is this correct? Two followups, if that's right: Can you open a local bank account, seeing that you are now permanently in Canada? Does your home bank allow mobile deposits using a smartphone, and, if so, do they allow them for foreign checks (presuming the check is from a Canadian bank, denominated in CAD)?

Comment: @RickGoldstein, yes that's right. No, I can't open a local bank account yet - I need a bunch more government paperwork first. No, my home (UK) bank doesn't do this - apparently it hasn't come to the UK yet.

Comment: Some banks also allow deposit of cheques via postal mail, if electronic presentation (e.g. smartphone capture) is not an option.